# Segmentation Fault when running multiple instances of Python Image Library (PIL)

Tags: python, c, windows, python-imaging-library

I wrote a Python program using the Python Image Library (PIL) that reads an image, makes some adjustments, and saves the file. I intend to put this on a web server so it's important to be able to run multiple instances of it at a time in case multiple users upload files to process concurrently.

I noticed though, that when I attempt to do this, the program crashes and gives a **Segmentation Fault**. I'm assuming this is due to some underlying C/C++ libraries in PIL that are trying to access/write the same blocks of memory?

I was under the impression that Python locks memory from separate processes to avoid these very kinds of faults.

What might cause this issue, and how can I effectively debug the source of this issue and fix it.

Comment: What are you using to run 'multiple instances'  of the library calls? Are you using explicit multi-threaded code in your own code, or are you relying on the Python WSGIserver to fork/create threads/use greenlets ?

Comment: When I start the script in multiple terminal windows, it crashes. Other scripts don't have this problem. I also run into trouble when I execute a child process from within node.js (using exec)

Comment: Have you considered Pillow? http://pillow.readthedocs.org/handbook/tutorial.html

Comment: I have not- is there much difference in syntax between the two libraries?